# Oracle autonumber trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got some SQL for a table in Oracle (Pre 12c) and my trigger doesn't seem to be working when i try and insert values into the student table i have to put a blank string for the primary key when i want to be able to put nothing and it propagate with a number.

Trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER student_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW

WHEN (new.record_number IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT student_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.record_number 
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 100 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

Student Table

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
record_number       NUMBER (8)
              CONSTRAINT  student_ref_number_pk PRIMARY KEY,

full_name         VARCHAR2(30)
              CONSTRAINT  student_full_name_nn  NOT NULL,

programme       VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT student_programme_fk
    REFERENCES programme (programme_name),

date_of_birth DATE,

term_address    VARCHAR2(255)
              CONSTRAINT student_term_address_nn  NOT NULL,

term_postcode VARCHAR2(8)
              CONSTRAINT student_term_postcode_nn NOT NULL,

home_address    VARCHAR2(255),

home_postcode VARCHAR2(7),

mobile_number NUMBER (11)
              CONSTRAINT student_mobile_number_nn NOT NULL,

home_number     NUMBER(11),

email_address   VARCHAR(255)
              CONSTRAINT student_email_address_nn NOT NULL,


username        VARCHAR2(20)
              CONSTRAINT student_username_nn  NOT NULL
)
```

Insert Values

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ('Tom', 'Networking', '', '123 lead street', 'PL48BZ', '345 HOME ROAD', 'DY15HGL', '07923584331', '01562748594', 'tom@gmail.com', 'tom22');
```

Error Message

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ('Tom', 'Networking', '', '123 lead street', 'PL48BZ', '345 HOME ROAD', 'DY104TJ', '07923584339', '01562748597', 'tom.mead07@hotmail.co.uk', 'tom225666')
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Always specify the column list in insert statements

Comment: `:NEW.record_number := COALESCE(NEW.record_number, student_seq.NEXTVAL);` is shorter and does the same as `WHEN ... SELECT ... INTO ... FROM dual;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - the end result is the same (though you missed a colon), but the `when` version is faster (in my testing) when the ID value is supplied by the insert, presumably as the trigger body doesn't run at all. Probably not enough of a difference to matter in most scenarios. Hopefully that's only done using the sequence directly in the insert... which is still quicker than setting it through the trigger, either way.

Answer (score 1):

@Mat is right. Your error message is because the insert statement is expecting every column to be specified in the VALUES clause.

```
insert into student(full_name, programme, ...) values ('billy', 'Networking',...)
```

... and the trigger fills in the record_number.

Answer (score 0):

If you cpecify a clumns and check values you find you forget the `record_number`. Either delete it from values or add null

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(
record_number
full_name,
programme,
date_of_birth,
term_address,
term_postcode,
home_address,
home_postcode,
mobile_number,
home_number ,
email_address,
username) VALUES (
<The values should be there> -- record_number
'Tom',                   -- full_name,
'Networking',            -- programme,
'',                      -- date_of_birth,
'123 lead street',       -- term_address,
'PL48BZ',                -- term_postcode,
'345 HOME ROAD',         -- home_address,
'DY15HGL',               -- home_postcode,
'07923584331',           -- mobile_number,
'01562748594',           -- home_number ,
'tom@gmail.com',         -- email_address,
'tom22');                -- username
```